# Stuck with compilation error with initializer list and this pointer

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list, this-pointer

I have very simple code here with a Rectangle and Circle class inheriting from Shape class, and output their area and perimeter. I can't figure out why it does not compile. The error message says

error: expected identifier before ‘this’
Rectangle(float width, float height): this->width(width), this->height(height){}
error expected '{' before 'this

So sth is not correct with my constructor initializer list. Before anyone suggests removal of the "this" pointer, I want to point out I'm aware the this pointer is not mandatory because the initializer can disambiguate. Removing the this pointer compilation goes fine, but I want to keep the this pointer and would like to know exactly what is the problem here.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <cmath>

#define PI 3.14159

class Shape{
public:
    virtual float Area() const = 0;
    virtual float Perimeter() const = 0;
};

class Rectangle: public Shape{
public:
    Rectangle(float width, float height): this->width(width), this->height(height){}
    float Area() const{return width*height;}
    float Perimeter() const{return 2*(width+height);}
private:
    float width{0};
    float height{0};
};

class Circle: public Shape{
public:
    Circle(float radius): this->radius(radius){}
    float Area() const{return PI*radius*radius;}
    float Perimeter() const{return 2.0*PI*radius;}
private:
    float radius{0};
};

// Test in main()
int main() {
  double epsilon = 0.1; // useful for floating point equality

  // Test circle
  Circle circle(12.31);
  assert(abs(circle.Perimeter() - 77.35) < epsilon);
  assert(abs(circle.Area() - 476.06) < epsilon);

  // Test rectangle
  Rectangle rectangle(10, 6);
  assert(rectangle.Perimeter() == 32);
  assert(rectangle.Area() == 60);
}
```

Comment: Side note: Why `#define PI 3.14159` rather than [std::numbers::pi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/constants)?

Comment: This is a good question, I think because of my lack of knowledge on every corner of the STL.

Comment: @YuZ Even if you wasn't aware of it, you should never use macros. You could always replace it by a constant namespace variable for example.

Comment: What is the advantage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Before anyone suggests removal of the "this" pointer, I want to point out I'm aware the this pointer is not mandatory

You're misunderstanding the options here. It's mandatory **not** to have it there. An initializer names the member you initialize. `this->width` isn't a name, but an expression.

Correct:
`Rectangle(float width, float height): width(width), height(height){}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm too stupid to follow. Originally I thought this pointer can't be used because the object has not yet been constructed. But I found out this is not the case. So what do you mean with "initializer names the member I initialize"? What is the difference between a name and expression?

Comment: @YuZ: Do you have a C++ textbook? Because _name_ is a rather fundamental concept, and so is _expression_. In this example, `->` is an operator, and `this->width` is a member access expression.

Comment: I think I understood. Does it mean usage of operators like "->" is forbidden in initializer lists? I may only put in the name of a member attribute and only written as such. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @YuZ: No. An initializer _list_ is a comma-separated list of _member initializers_. Each member initializer has two parts: the _name_ of the member (or base class) to initialize, and the initializer _expression_. As noted before, `this->member` is an member access expression, so it can only appear in the initializer expression part, not in the name part.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I think I understood! It was my pleasure and an honor to be lectured by a C++ expert wiith 10 gold badges!